# How to check for null fields in allocated array in C

Tags: arrays, c, memory, null

I have an allocated array and need to go over all fields and compare non null values. Values in this array can also be 0 which is causing some trouble for me.

```
int size = 4;
int *numbers = (int*) malloc(size * 4);

// Fill some fields
numbers[0] = 3;
numbers[1] = 0;
numbers[2] = 6;

// Search and find min value's index
int min = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] != NULL) {
        if (numbers[i] < numbers[min]) min = i;
    } else {
        // Code if value is null here
    }
}

printf("%d\n", min);
```

Im not sure how to compare properly with NULL. What is the correct way?

Comment: In C, there is no difference between NULL and 0.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny well... `0` is just an integer literal, while `NULL` is `((void *)0)`

Comment: You do _not_ want to compare an `int` value against `NULL` when you really want to compare against `0`. 99.44% of systems, `NULL` is zero, but it's _not_ a guarantee. Also, most systems do: `#define NULL ((void *) 0)`, so the compiler should flag the comparison of an `int` value against a pointer

Comment: @CraigEstey It is guaranteed, though, that a zero integer literal, or such a literal cast to a pointer type, works equivalently to `NULL`, even if the internal representation of a null pointer of that type is not all bits zero.

Comment: Integer variables in C are not nullable, like you may be used to in other programming languages.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny "there is no difference between NULL and 0. "--> `NULL` may be a pointer, an `int` or `long` etc.,  `NULL`, at least, may differ in size than 0 ( an `int`).

Answer (score 1):

Your overall design is flawed. You should not treat `NULL` as a catch-all zero value. `NULL` is a special *pointer* value, not simply an integer. If you compare an `int` against `NULL`, you're comparing two different types, which is not a good idea. Furthermore, you're comparing a scalar type with a pointer type, which is even worse.

> Values in this array can also be 0 which is causing some trouble for me.

If this is the case, you cannot use `0` as both a value and a "mark" for "non present value". Problem is, you cannot use `NULL` either, because it's a different type. If you try using it, the compiler will warn you (or at least it should, if you enable warnings). At best, assigning `NULL` will implicitly convert it to `int` and result in `0` since `NULL` is usually defined just as `((void *)0)`, so it will be impossible to distinguish between NULL-ed values and valid values.

You will have to reserve one of the values between `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` for this purpose:

```
#include <limits.h>

enum { NOT_PRESENT = INT_MIN };

int size = 4;
int *numbers = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

// Initialize all to NOT_PRESENT
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    numbers[i] = NOT_PRESENT;

// Fill some fields
numbers[0] = 3;
numbers[1] = 0;
numbers[2] = 6;

// Search and find min value's index
int min = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] != NOT_PRESENT) {
        if (numbers[i] < numbers[min]) min = i;
    } else {
        // Code if value is not present here
    }
}

printf("%d\n", min);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your allocated array elements will never be NULL. Even the memory that is freed from using free function is not NULL. IT can  points to anything may be any ur own program address space or outside address space.

Ur code looks OK. The value that u did not assigned to element at index 3 can have garbage but not NULL

Comment: The uninitialised value can compare equal to `NULL`, though.

Comment: @Arkku if I do `char *p=malloc(..)` then it's not unitialized in a way that it must be pointing to some garbage value. IN C OR in memory there are chances more in favor of that it may be point to something even if it's garbage. So memory allocated from suceesful malloc can't have `(char*)0` or NULL

Comment: _Side note:_ I'm not totally sure, but I've rarely seen `ur` for `your` and `u` for `you` on SO [except on newbie questions]. `SO != twitter`? I have seen others, such as IMO, AFAIK, AFAICT, IIRC

Comment: @user786 C standard §6.3.2.3.3 defines null pointer constant as “an integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *”, so `NULL` can be just `#define NULL 0`, therefore it is entirely possible, and even likely, that a "garbage" value in memory compares equal to zero. Furthermore, the undefined value in uninitialised memory can be any bit pattern, so even if you were comparing it to a runtime null pointer (and not `NULL`) that had a non-zero bit representation, it's still one of the possible bit patterns that could be in memory.

Comment: And in any case the whole null speculation is besides the point, it's just one value among many. In the OP's 32-bit machine (based on allocating `size * 4` memory), each garbage value is one of 2³² possible values, so there is at least 1 chance in that many to compare equal to any given constant (and not all values are equally likely to occur; in fact they can be quite deterministic in practice). And of course one could speculate that use of the uninitialised value is probably undefined behaviour, so the compiler could theoretically generate code to do whatever.